# Rebuild or Maintain a connection between android and MySQL database

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am creating an app with a html, css, js inside a webview, and also several databases to store data. My app is designed to be used for 10 to 11 hours each time.

A big problem was found that android will kill my app in background after leaving for a while. However, app gets killed will lead to a big problem as it means the whole task has to redo again. I have to maintain OR rebuild the connection between database and android to ensure my app can keep running smoothly.

I would like to know:
1.) is there any way to maintain the connection between database and android (e.g. put it in foreground service?) so that killing app will not affect the connection?

2.) can I ask android and js to rebuild the connection (e.g. synchronize the database?) between android and js after the app get killed by OS?

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    HTMLDataBase myDB1;
    ContentTableDataBase myDB2;
    CloudTableDataBase myDB3;
    InterviewDataBase myDB4;
    Context context;
    boolean check;
    private WebView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myDB1 = new HTMLDataBase(this);
        myDB2 = new ContentTableDataBase(this);
        myDB3 = new CloudTableDataBase(this); 
        myDB4 = new InterviewDataBase(this); 

        display_html();
        Javascript_Android_Communication();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        myDB1 = new HTMLDataBase(this); 
        myDB2 = new ContentTableDataBase(this); 
        myDB3 = new CloudTableDataBase(this);
        myDB4 = new InterviewDataBase(this);

        display_html();
        Javascript_Android_Communication();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();

        this.finish();
    }

    public void display_html()
    {
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    public void Javascript_Android_Communication()
    {
        WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
        WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        view.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
        view.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptInterface(this), "app");
    }
}
```

WebViewJavaScriptInterface:

```
    public class WebViewJavaScriptInterface
    {
        HTMLDataBase myDB1;
        ContentTableDataBase myDB2;
        CloudTableDataBase myDB3;
        InterviewDataBase myDB4;
        Context mContext;

        WebViewJavaScriptInterface (Context c)
        {
            mContext = c;
        }
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void Javascript_to_Android(String data_id, String html_element, String state)
        {
            myDB1 = new HTMLDataBase((MainActivity) mContext);
            myDB1.updateData(data_id, html_element, state);
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void Javascript_to_Content_Table_DataBase(String data_id, String duty_time, String my_duty, String checkbox)
        {
            myDB2 = new ContentTableDataBase((MainActivity) mContext);
            myDB2.insertData(data_id, duty_time, my_duty, checkbox);
        }


        @JavascriptInterface
        public void add_cloud_data(String data_id, String Time, String Total_Cloud, String Low_Medium_Cloud, String FirstCloud,
                               String SecondCloud, String ThirdCloud, String ForthCloud, String FifthCloud, String SixthCloud,
                               String SeventhCloud, String EighthCloud, String Visibility)
        {
            myDB3 = new CloudTableDataBase((MainActivity) mContext);
            boolean response = myDB3.insertData(data_id, Time, Total_Cloud, Low_Medium_Cloud, FirstCloud, SecondCloud, ThirdCloud, ForthCloud, FifthCloud, SixthCloud, SeventhCloud, EighthCloud, Visibility);
            if (response == true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (response == false)
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void update_cloud_data(String data_id, String Time, String Total_Cloud, String Low_Medium_Cloud, String FirstCloud,
                               String SecondCloud, String ThirdCloud, String ForthCloud, String FifthCloud, String SixthCloud,
                               String SeventhCloud, String EighthCloud, String Visibility)
        {
            myDB3 = new CloudTableDataBase((MainActivity) mContext);
            boolean response = myDB3.updateData(data_id, Time, Total_Cloud, Low_Medium_Cloud, FirstCloud, SecondCloud, ThirdCloud, ForthCloud, FifthCloud, SixthCloud, SeventhCloud, EighthCloud, Visibility);
            if (response == true)
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Data updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (response == false)
            {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Data not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void delete_duty(String id)
        {
            myDB2.deleteData(id);
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void delete_cloud(String id)
        {
            myDB3.deleteData(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your architecture needs to be more robust. You should structure your system so that, if the user leaves the app for some period of time and Android kills the app, after restart of the app it can continue where it left off. This means saving the current state at strategic moments and being able to restore that state after continuing. There is nothing you can do to prevent Android from killing your app if the user puts it in the background to do something else. This is just the nature of mobile apps and you need to program accordingly.

Comment: I know what you mean and this is the reason why I build up databases. Databases help rebuild the html by providing all the data it needs. The problem is, the connection between databases and android is broken after the app is killed. My question is, how shall I rebuild or maintain the connection between them?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "the connection between databases and android is broken after the app is killed." How is the connection created/managed?

Comment: If Android kills off the app while in the background, when the user returns to the app, Android will start the app again. It will need to go through whatever mechanism you have to restore connection to the database. I don't know enough about your whole architecture to tell you more.

Comment: Information updated. The following error message is shown when I restart the app after the app gets killed: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.sahelper.ContentTableDataBase.deleteData(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference".

Comment: I would need more information about what happens when Android starts your app again. It isn't clear to me what is going on. You might want to edit your question and add that information. Also, why do you call `finish()` in `onStop()`? This seems super strange to me

Comment: You might want to add some debug logging to see what is happening when the user returns to your app after it has been killed. Normally Android will launch the app again if the user returns to it after it has been killed off.

Comment: From the error message you put in the comment, it looks like the JS code in the web page is calling a "delete" method before `myDB2` or `myDB3` have been initialized.